# Instruct EF6 to delete first, then update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, unique-constraint, savechanges

I have a join table representing a many-to-many relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CoUndertaker](
  [ProposalID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [CoUndertakerID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [Order] [tinyint] NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT [PK_CoUndertaker] PRIMARY KEY ([ProposalID] ASC, [CoUndertakerID] ASC)
, CONSTRAINT [UQ_CoUndertakerOrder] UNIQUE ([ProposalID] ASC, [Order] ASC)
)
```

As seen above, I declared a unique constraint because I want `[Order]` values unique within the same `Proposal`.

My app needs to modify the `CoUndertakers` collection of existing `Proposal` data. Say a `Proposal` currently has two `CoUndertaker`s with `[Order]` values of `0` and `1` respectively, I might have to delete the first one and update the `[Order]` value of the second one from `1` to `0`. Below is how I basically do this in C#:

```
// ... Locating coUndertakerToDelete and coUndertakerToUpdateOrder from proposal.CoUndertakers ...
dbContext.CoUndertakers.Remove(coUndertakerToDelete);
coUndertakerToUpdateOrder.Order = 0;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

When running I got SqlException saying that the unique constraint is violated, the unique index value `(2, 0)` already exists. (`2` is the value of `proposal.ID`)

As long as I remove the unique constraint from the table definition in DB, the same C# code finishes without exception, and in DB the `Order` value of the remaining `[CoUndertaker]` record does get changed to `0`. So apparently EF6 does update before delete, which results in unique constraint violation.

Is there a way I can instruct EF6 to do deletion first, then update remaining data?

Comment: Easy way out would be to run that in explicit transaction and so 2 `SaveChanges` one after another. I'm not sure if EF has any way for you to instruct it about ordering of operations you need.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately EF will not execute statements in the order that you make changes. This is one case where you would need to use multiple `SaveChanges` calls to ensure the order of operations is consistent to avoid your unique constraint being violated. To avoid the possibility of data being stored in an invalid state (Delete passes, but Update fails for any reason, leaving no "0" record) it would be advisable to wrap the two operations in a transaction:

```
using (var tx = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        dbContext.CoUndertakers.Remove(coUndertakerToDelete);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        coUndertakerToUpdateOrder.Order = 0;
        dbContext.SaveChanges();         
        tx.Commit();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {  // TODO: Log ex.
        tx.Rollback();
    }
}
```

This may get more complicated if there are other entities with changes pending as to whether the rest of any state changes are "complete" when we need to ensure a Delete is committed.